# Issue passing struct through method/function in c

Tags: c, function, methods, attributes, dereference

I am having issues with the following method. It supposed to change the value of `mq.queue[qCounter].id` to that found in `ident` and it does this but the value is not retained outside after the method is done. It only seems to change while in the method. I tried de-referencing the attribute `mq` but and there were no compilation errors but the program stopped running whenever it got to the method. Any ideas how I can fix it/ achieve the same thing using a method/function?

```
void createQ(MsgQs_t mq, int ident){
    int taken=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(mq.queue[i].id==ident){
            printf("That Queue Id is already taken\n");
            taken=1;
        }
    }
    if(taken==0){
    mq.queue[qCounter].id=ident;
    printf("THE INNER ID IS %d and the qCounter is %d\n", mq.queue[qCounter].id, qCounter);
    qCounter++;
    }
}
```

The following is the struct im using aka "MsgQs mq" above:

```
typedef struct MessQ {//A single message queue
    char message[MQS][MLN];
    int id;
}MessQ_t;

typedef struct MsgQs {//An array of message queues
    MessQ_t queue[MQA];
}MsgQs_t;
```

Comment: `MsgQs_t mq`is pass by value make it as a pointer to have a change in the caller function

Answer (score 1):

In function  `createQ` argument `MsgQs_t mq` used as `pass-by-value` and hence caller component will not have any changes upon editing in `mq`

Change code to `pass-by-reference` something like,

```
 void createQ(MsgQs_t *mq, int ident){
//                    ^^^^^^ Here
        int taken=0;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(mq->queue[i].id==ident){
  //           ^^^^^^ Here change dot(.) to this (->) for access
                    printf("That Queue Id is already taken\n");
                    taken=1;
                }
            }
            if(taken==0){
            mq->queue[qCounter].id=ident;
            printf("THE INNER ID IS %d and the qCounter is %d\n", mq->queue[qCounter].id, qCounter);
            qCounter++;
            }
        }
```

While calling the function send the address as follows,

```
createQ(&mq, indent_value);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but im relatively new to C. How do i change the parameters where u wrote "^^^^^^ Here" to make it pass-by-pointer cause i thought adding the * made it pass-by-pointer

Comment: Please https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference/amp/ this for more information